# How to filter a list of tuples for every row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples, nltk

I'm trying to filter a list of tuples which second element start with 'V' in order to clean my dataframe.

i have a pandas dataframe call  'df_my_string' like :

[image]

a sample is:

```
verbs_tokens
[('[', 'NNS'), ("'Europe", "''"), ('was', 'VBD'), ('always', 'RB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('future', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ("'", "''"), (']', 'NN')]
[('[', 'IN'), ("'Europe", 'CD'), ('marks', 'NNS'), ('its', 'PRP$'), ('anniversary', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('it', 'PRP'), ('is', 'VBZ')]
```

What I need is keep the tuples for each row that the second value start with "V"

I have tried many ways but I can not figure out how:

```
 #df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens']=filter((lambda x: x[1].startswith('V')),df_my_string[['verbs_tokens']])
#df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = df_my_string.verbs_tokens.apply(lambda x: str(x[0][1]).startswith('V'))
#df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = df_my_string.verbs_tokens.apply(lambda x: str(x[0][1]).startswith('V'))
#df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = [tup for tup in df_my_string['verbs_tokens'] if str(tup[0][1])=='V']
#df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = [item  for item in df_my_string['verbs_tokens'] if pd.Series(re.search('^V.*',item[0][1])).reset_index(drop=True).values]
```

The expected output:

```
verbs_tokens
[('was', 'VBD')]
[('is', 'VBZ')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = df_my_string["verbs_tokens"].apply(lambda x: [t for t in x if t[1].lower().startswith("v")])

>>> df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens']
0    [(was, VBD)]
1     [(is, VBZ)]
Name: clean_verbs_tokens, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# this is wrong because x is containing list of tuples
# so basically you are applying the condition only on 
# the first tuple
df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = df_my_string.verbs_tokens.apply(lambda x: str(x[0][1]).startswith('V'))
```

```
# try this
df_my_string['clean_verbs_tokens'] = df_my_string.verbs_tokens.apply(lambda x: [tup for tup in x if tup[1][0]=="V"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    { 
       'Tuples' :  [ [('[', 'IN'), ("'Europe", 'CD'), ('marks', 'NNS'), ('its', 'PRP$'), ('anniversary', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('it', 'PRP'), ('is', 'VBZ')],
[('[', 'NNS'), ("'Europe", "''"), ('was', 'VBD'), ('always', 'RB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('future', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ("'", "''"), (']', 'NN')] ]
    } )
```

Define a function to find tuple start with any char:

```
def find_char(tuples , char):
    start_with_char = []
    
    for tp in tuples: 
        if tp[1][:1]  == char:
                start_with_char.append(tp)
                
    return start_with_char
```

Apply the function on your dataframe:

```
df['Tuples'].apply(lambda row: find_char(row ,'V')   )
```

Result :

```
0     [(is, VBZ)]
1    [(was, VBD)]
```

Note: this solution will give you a list of tuples that has the char